# How to define a hashtable as payload in Constraint option with XML?

Tags: symfony

Trying to customize the FOSUserbundle User Entity, I want to assert the username with a constraint and some data in an array as payload.

Doing it with annotations, I would do it so :

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Length(..., payload={"my_array":{"Hello1","Hello2"}})
     */
    protected $username;
}
```

But to extend the FOSUserbundle constraints, it must be done with XML :

```
<constraint name="Length">
    ...
    <option name="payload"><!-- What I tried but it doesn't work -->
        <value>
            <option name="my_array">
                <value>Hello1</value>
                <value>Hello2</value>
            </option>   
        </value>
    </option>
</constraint>
```

I cannot use 'option name="..."' to define a hashtable ? How can I write it ?
Nothing found in Symfony doc.

The error with the try above :
Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping}option': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping}constraint

But the link http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it, nested 'value' element must be set like :

```
<constraint name="Length">
    ...
    <option name="payload"><!-- What I tried but it doesn't work -->
        <value key="my_array">
            <value>Hello1</value>
            <value>Hello2</value>
        </value>
    </option>
</constraint>
```